# how to store each month's data in separate variable

Tags: python

I have a 3 years dataset. I have split my dataset in days. now, I want to store each month's data in a separate list/variable.

```py
SDD2=Restaurant[Restaurant.Item == ' Soft Drink '].groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='D')).sum()
print(SDD2)
```

[This a data which I get from above code now I want to store each month data in separate variable/list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLZnK.png)

Comment: What about `groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='M'))`? It will give you an iterable of (month, dataset).

Comment: it gives the data of month i but what i want is list of a single month in which there is a data of that month e.g if want a jan 2011  data then in a list there should a data of days

Comment: Just imagine you have no background for the assignment and all you know is what is written in the question. How could I guess what the dataframe contains, and what you  want... Without more details, this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2):

You should store data into json format or csv format of each of month into file so it easily accessible from your python script.

For more information check python's module **JSON** and **CSV**.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="M"))` and then query on the groups to get your data with `get_group('date')` or optionally you could convert the grouped data to dict of lists with either `.apply(list).to_dict()` or `dict(list(groups))`.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some random dates
start = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2019-12-31')

start_u = start.value//10**9
end_u = end.value//10**9

date_range = pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, 30), unit='s')

# convert to DF
df = pd.DataFrame(date_range, columns=["Date"])
# Add random data
df['Data'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(len(date_range)))

# Format to y-m-d
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

print(df)

# group by month
grouped_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="M"))

# query the groups
print("\n\ngrouped data for feb 2018\n")
#print(grouped_df.get_group('2018-02-28'))

dict_of_list = dict(list(grouped_df))

feb_2018 = pd.Timestamp('2018-02-28')

if feb_2018 in dict_of_list:
    print(dict_of_list[feb_2018])
```